# A problems with detect data

Tags: web-scraping, data-mining

The task is download the table with names of bookmakers and odds ([here](http://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/chile/primera-division/san-marcos-de-arica-s-wanderers-SYhSAhri/?r=1)). 
I can not find in source code part which corresponds to these data. I tried to use chrome extension named SelectorGadget, unsuccessfuly.
Similarly, when I want to open matches ([matches](http://www.oddsportal.com/matches/soccer/20160115/)) I meet same problem.  Thank you for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

The data is not in the HTML, it is dynamically loaded via JavaScript.

From the [Terms of Service](http://www.oddsportal.com/terms/):

> Without prior authorisation in writing from the Provider, **Visitors are not authorised to copy**, modify, tamper with, distribute, transmit, display, reproduce, transfer, upload, **download** or otherwise use or alter **any of the content** of the Website.

Therefore, do not expect us to assist you with breaching their terms of use.

Comment: Ups. It is my fault. In any case, thank you for an answer.